# Ansible playbook to check OS and given mount points

Tags: ansible

Below is my playbook to check to verify OS and Mount points. Getting below error and couldn't debug it. The issue seems to be with the later part "Verify Mount points"

```
---
 - hosts: all
   gather_facts: true
   vars:
    M1: ['RedHat','7']
    M2: ['/u01','/u02']
   tasks:
    - name: "Verify OS"
      when: >
       not ((ansible_os_family == M1[0] and ansible_distribution_major_version == M1[1]))
      fail:
       msg: "OS not supported"

    - name: "Verify Mount Points"
      with_items: ansible_mounts
      when: >
       not ((item.mount == M2[0] and item.mount == M2[1]))
      fail:
       msg: "Mount Point doesn't exist"
```

Output:
ansible-playbook -i dbservers test.yml

```
    PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.107]
ok: [192.168.0.109]

TASK [Verify OS] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.0.109]
skipping: [192.168.0.107]

TASK [Verify Mount Points] ******************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.0.109]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'not ((item.mount == M2[0] and item.mount == M2[1]))\n' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (not ((item.mount == M2[0] and item.mount == M2[1]))\n): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'mount'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/test.yml': line 14, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: \"Verify Mount Points\"\n      ^ here\n"}
fatal: [192.168.0.107]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'not ((item.mount == M2[0] and item.mount == M2[1]))\n' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (not ((item.mount == M2[0] and item.mount == M2[1]))\n): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'mount'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/test.yml': line 14, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: \"Verify Mount Points\"\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.0.107              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
192.168.0.109              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set `gather_facts: true` when using ansible defined variables.

Second, try to focus on the main issue here. Something along these lines should work:

```yaml
---
 - hosts: all
   gather_facts: true
   vars:
     M1: ['RedHat','7']
     M2: ['/u01','/u02']
   tasks:
    - name: "Verifying os and mount points"
      debug:
         msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ansible_os_family 
        - ansible_distribution_major_version
        - ansible_mounts
      when: 
        - not item.ansible_os_family == 'M1[0]'  # you could also replace 'M1[0]' with 'Redhat'.
        - item.ansible_distribution_major_version == 'M1[1]'. # you could also replace 'M1[1]' with '7'.

     - fail:
         msg: "mount points not correctly"
       loop: ansible_mounts
       when: 
         - item.mount is defined
         - item.mount != 'M2[0]'
         - item.mount == 'M2[1]'
```

You shouldn't specify multiple `fails` in a single task, as [fail is it's own task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what the output is of your play.

Comment: I have modified my code and now it seems the later part where I want the specific mount point is having an issue